# Does anyone know when the ASP.NET MVC will be fully released?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When do you think we can expect the full release version of ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***EDIT (16/Jul/2009)***

Updating to ensure this page contains the most recent details.

ASP.NET MVC is now fully released ***http://www.asp.net/mvc/***.

---

***EDIT (28/Jan/2009)***

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 RC Now Available.... final next month ([From ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx))

> Today’s RC is the last public release
>   of ASP.NET MVC that we’ll ship prior
>   to the final “1.0” release.  We expect
>   to ship the final ASP.NET MVC 1.0
>   release next month.

---

Last I heard, Q4 2008.

Scott Hanselman posted this [in his blog about 3.5 SP1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HiddenGemsNotTheSameOld35SP1Post.aspx)

> **What about ASP.NET MVC?**
>
> There is likely some confusion around
>   MVC as a few people expected ASP.NET
>   MVC to ship in SP1. This is probably
>   because MVC was included in 3.5
>   "Extensions Preview." However, the
>   plan was always to ship in Q4CY08.
>
> *(That date is marketing speak, I've
>   just learned. I tell people what Eilon
>   told me - it'll ship in a month ending
>   in "-ber." Possible "March-ber" but
>   also maybe "next June-ber.")*
>
> Anyway, Phil has always said that MVC
>   is on its own schedule and will ship
>   when its done. Possibly when Duke
>   Nukem Forever ships.

Comment: Hurray for Duke Nukem Forever.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only speculations right now. I will then speculate that we will have a Beta in December (they said the next preview will  be the Beta) and a full Release in February-March 2009.